# Can we hide or encrypt the get method address in AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, encryption

Can I hide or encrypt the GET method address which displays in the address bar of the browser?

I'm asking this question in relevant to both ajax and jquery.

[image]

Comment: you can't hide. Instead encrypt you can use routes

Comment: can you please tell me how can I do that?

Comment: Or a link to how to do that will be useful for me.

Comment: You can do it by using htaccess. If you are not using any server side framework.

Comment: Try this jquery library - https://github.com/thorsteinsson/jquery-routes

Comment: you can encrypt your data appended in URL (GET method) , but hiding whole url or encrypt whole url is not possible

Comment: @Harsha You have to think about who you want to protect the URL query from and why. If you've done that, you can share that with us by editing your question to include the missing information

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no, you cannot hide that.

Somewhere along the line, your javascript has to make a call to the correct URL to fetch any information with AJAX. There are ways to obfuscate this URL, but it can always be reverse engineered by someone that cares enough to do so. 'Security through obscurity' does not work and is not at all recommended.

What you could do however is make a request to a script on the server which determines if a person is allowed to access a particular set of information, and then stream back the results. But there is no way to hide a browser URL.

Answer (score 0):

Have to include jQuery routes. I hope this example may help you.

```
 var newsModule = {
            fetch: function() {
                $('#news').load('news.php?id=' + this.id).show();
            }
            fetchAll: function() {
                $('#news').load('news.php').show();
            }
        };

        $.routes.add('/news/{id:int}/', newsModule.fetch);
        $.routes.add('/news/', newsModule.fetchAll);
```